# HTML parsing in VBA

Tags: html, vba, xmlhttprequest, html-parsing

I'm trying to update fund sizes with morningstar's website. My previous attempt with IE automation didn't work so I switched to XML httpRequest (works also significantly faster). Now I'm having difficulties with getting the right lines printed out of the document I get from the website. I want the code to give me the 3rd "td"-tag within a "tr"-tag that's 1st "td"-tag is called "Fund Size (Mil)". So the code loops through all the "td"-tags' headings and jumps into action if it finds that `"{line heading}" = "Fund Size (Mil)"`. Now this is the problem. I don't know how to refer to these headings.

I tried to set each "td"-tag as a variable (there are 3 "td"-tags in a "tr"-tag, so I had variables row1, row2, row3 for each "td-tag") but when I try to do this now, I get a *run-time error 438: object doesn't support this property or method* in line

```
Debug.Print TDElements.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).Cells(0).innerHTML
```

Additionally, when I `Debug.Print TDElement.innerHTML`, I don't see the "td"-tags I need. When I put `.innerText` in the end instead, I see all the "td"-tags.

Now the questions are:
1) How can I refer to the headings directly? (See the commented lines of code inside `For Each` loop below)
2) What may be the reason I don't see all the td-tags with .innerHTML but I see them with .innerText?

Url
http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04BKW
Excel 2010, IE version 11.

```
Sub XMLhttpRequestTest2()

'Microsoft XML, v 6.0
'Microsoft HTML object library, used in parsing HTML

Dim myurl As String
Dim TDElement As Object
Dim TDElements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody

Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body


myurl = "http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04BKW"
IE.Open "GET", myurl, False
IE.send

HTMLBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText

Set TDElements = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each TDElement In TDElements
        Debug.Print TDElement.innerText '.innerText/.innerHTML. Can't see the fund size with .innerHTML??
'        If "{line heading}" = "Fund Size (Mil)" Then    'How can I refer to headings in the html document?
'            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3") = Split("{line text}", ";")(1) 'reference to line text?
    Next


End Sub
```

**h2so4's answer fixed the above issue. Below is an extension to the initial question.**

Now the TDElement  gets assigned a couple lines of text (I switched h2so4's value 10 to 3, so the code displays the next 3 lines when fundsize string is found). How can I parse this further? Current line `Worksheets("helper").Cells(x, 6).Value = Split(TDElement.innerText, " ")(1)` returns the value I need (769.28), but for the future it’d be helpful if I really understood what’s exactly happening here.

So, just for exercise, how would I get all the 3 lines printed in their own cells? So the output would be: Fund Size (Mil), 31/08/2017, 769.28 in cells (x,6), (x,7), (x,8). When I try functions “Split” or “Left” to TDElement, the functions only target the last row, not the other rows above. However, when I `Debug.Print TDElement.innerText` / `.innerHTML`, I see also the other lines. So how could I “get access” to the rows above the last row?

Output of `Debug.Print TDElement.innerText` :

Fund Size (Mil)

31/08/2017

EUR 769.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code will get you to the "fund size" line

```
Sub XMLhttpRequestTest2()

'Microsoft XML, v 6.0
'Microsoft HTML object library, used in parsing HTML

    Dim myurl As String
    Dim TDElement As Object
    Dim TDElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim Flag As Boolean
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody
    Dim k As Long
    Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body


    myurl = "http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04BKW"
    IE.Open "GET", myurl, False
    IE.send

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = IE.responseText
    Flag = False
    k = 0
    Set TDElements = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each TDElement In TDElements
        If InStr(TDElement.innerText, "Fund Size") <> 0 Or Flag Then
            'if fundsize string is found, display the next 10 lines
            Debug.Print ":" & TDElement.innerText  '.innerText/.innerHTML. Can't see the fund size with .innerHTML??
            '        If "{line heading}" = "Fund Size (Mil)" Then    'How can I refer to headings in the html document?
            '            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3") = Split("{line text}", ";")(1) 'reference to line text?
            k = k + 1
            If k < 10 Then Flag = True Else Flag = False
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. I modified your code by declaring a new integer variable n and set it to 3 instead of  10 (targets only the lines I need). I, however, would like to know why I can parse only the last row the code returns. Please see the **extension to the initial question** above.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your extension, the way to split the answer depends on the way the page has been designed. here is a possible solution to get your data in 3 differents cells.

```
Sub XMLhttpRequestTest2()

'Microsoft XML, v 6.0
'Microsoft HTML object library, used in parsing HTML

    Dim myurl As String
    Dim TDElement As Object
    Dim TDElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim Flag As Boolean
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody
    Dim k As Long, text
    Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body


    myurl = "http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04BKW"
    IE.Open "GET", myurl, False
    IE.send

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = IE.responseText
    Flag = False
    k = 0
    Set TDElements = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each TDElement In TDElements
        If InStr(TDElement.innerText, "Fund Size") <> 0 Or Flag Then
            'if fundsize string is found, display the next 10 lines
            text = Split(TDElement.innerText, vbLf)
            If text(0) <> "" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, k + 2).Resize(, UBound(text) + 1) = text    '.innerText/.innerHTML. Can't see the fund size with .innerHTML??
                '        If "{line heading}" = "Fund Size (Mil)" Then    'How can I refer to headings in the html document?
                '            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3") = Split("{line text}", ";")(1) 'reference to line text?
            End If
            k = k + 1
            If k < 3 Then Flag = True Else Flag = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```